# Counting Problem: combination from categories

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$ categories, each category has $a_i$ **different** items, where $a_i \ge 1$ and $1 \le i \le n$.  How many possible **combinations** are there to get 1 item from $k$ different categories? (given $1 \le k \le n$)

Is there a fast formula for this problem? (calculator allowed, but no recursion/loop based algorithms)?

Edit: to make the question more clear

Comment: Seems unlikely - it is the coefficient of $x^k$ when you expand $(1+a_1x)(1+a_2x)\cdots(1+a_nx)$. If I'm interpreting the question correctly...

Answer (score 1):

It is the sum of all possible $k$ products of the $a_i$'s. The number of ways to do this is,

\begin{align*}
s = \sum_{i_1,i_2,...,i_k} a_{i_1}.a_{i_2}...a_{i_k}, \mbox{ such that all the indices in a product are distinct} 
\end{align*}

There are ${n \choose k}$, as in each term all $i_j$'s are distinct. In the general case, there will be no explicit formula. However, perhaps if there is some structure to the $a_i$'s , then a closed form formula may be possible

Comment: Also known as the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $k$.